# How to pass multiple record to the child from the parent with fork

Tags: c, pipe, fork

What I am trying to do is, I have a parent and child process. I try to read a file and pass all of the content to the child. The input file has records in it. I have to read once at a time and pass to the child. But no matter what I do. child only reads the first record, not all of the others. I tested my method gets all records from the input file but cannot write all of them to the child. Any idea please.

```
struct product_record {
    int idnumber;            // Unique identification
    char name[PRODUCTSIZE];  // String description
    double price;            // Unit cost
};

int pid, mypipe[2], status;

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
    int result;     
    result = pipe(mypipe);//create pipes    
    if (result < 0) {
       perror("pipe creation error");//failure in creating a pipe
       exit (1);    
    }//if

    if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        read(mypipe[0], &product, sizeof(product));
        exit(0);
    } 
    else if (pid == -1) 
    {
         cout << "Fork failed" << endl;
         exit(1);
    } 
    else 
    {//parent
        parentReadsFromTheFile(argv);//argv inputfile name
        wait(&status);
    }   
    return 0;//Return to the OS.
}//main

void parentReadsFromTheFile(char **args) 
{
    while (getline(inputFile, line)) //read a line till EOF
    {
        //put read record into product
        write(mypipe[1], &product, sizeof(product));//Write to pipe
    }
}
```

Comment: Align your code correctly and don't comment the obvious.

Comment: Post the definition of `product`.

Comment: I edited and explained better. Thanks.

Comment: How much is `PRODUCTSIZE` ?

Comment: `child only reads the first record` - that would be because you told it to read one record? `read(mypipe[0], &product, sizeof(product)); exit(0);`

Answer (score 1):

You can transmit data via pipes from a process to another, but this data must only contain scalar information: you cannot transmit addresses or pointers this way.

I suspect your `product` object is not a simple structure with just numbers and characters.

From the type you posted for `product`, this type can be transmitted this way.

Re-reading your code, I see that the child only reads one record:

```
if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    read(mypipe[0], &product, sizeof(product));
    exit(0);
}
```

Your write: *no matter what I do. child only reads the first record, not all of the others.*, but that's exactly what you do!

As a matter of fact, be aware that `read` may return a short count in some conditions that you should support, but in the current case, you only try to read a single structure and exit the process.  Further writes by the parent to to the pipe will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your "child only reads the first record, not all of the others", is because you `exit()` immediately after reading once:

```
if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
{
    read(mypipe[0], &product, sizeof(product));
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: "is because you exit() immediately after reading once:" I removed the exit. Still did not work out/

Comment: @user2934615: Removing `exit()` obviously isn't enough. You'll have to write code that makes it read the rest of the records, it won't do it by itself...